# Adding fade animation to CSS-only mobile menu drawer

Tags: css, mobile, menu

I'm using the CSS-only mobile menu drawer at http://www.scottohara.me/article/morph-button-updated.html -- however if it has a lot of content it might look a bit odd when contracting.

**Therefore, how does one add a fade animation to the menu when expanding and contracting?**

```
/* NO LUCK WITH THIS ONE */
#nav-expand:checked + .nav-side { opacity: 0; }
#nav-expand:checked + .nav-side .menu-list { opacity: 1; }
```

```css
 *, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 2;
  margin: 0; }

body {
  background: #444;
  overflow-x: hidden; }

p {
  margin-bottom: 24px; }
  p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0; }

.content {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 20px; }

.invis {
  height: 1px;
  left: -999px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -999px;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 1px; }

.main-base {
  background: #eee;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s; }

  .main-base header, .main-base footer {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff; }

footer a {
  color: #fff; }

.nav-side {
  background: #56cee8;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 60px;
  left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: fixed;
  transition: all .3s;
  width: 60px;
  z-index: 2;}

.menu-list {
  height: 0%;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all .3s; }
  .menu-list a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 8px;
    text-decoration: none; }
    .menu-list a:hover {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }

.btn-label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0; }
  .btn-label .top {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    right: 12px;
  }
  .btn-label .middle {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    left: 12px;
    right: 12px;
  }
  .btn-label .bottom {
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    left: 12px;
    right: 12px;
  }
  .btn-label .label {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side .btn-label {
    display: none;
  }

.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; }
  #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side .close {
    display: block;
  }

/* TRY ADDING FADE ANIMATION */
#nav-expand:checked + .nav-side { opacity: 0; }
#nav-expand:checked + .nav-side .menu-list { opacity: 1; }

#nav-expand:checked + .nav-side {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px; }
  #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side .menu-list {
    height: 100%; }
  #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side .btn-label {
    color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px; }
  #nav-expand:checked + .nav-side + .main-base {
    left: 200px; }
  #nav-collapse + .main-base {
    left: 200px; }
  #nav-collapse + .main-base > .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .3s; }
  #nav-collapse:checked + .main-base {
    left: 0; }
  #nav-collapse:checked + .main-base > .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0; }
```

```html
 <div class="page">

    <input type="radio" id="nav-expand" name="nav" class="invis" />
    <nav class="nav-side">
      <label for="nav-collapse" class="close">
        &times;
      </label>
      <label for="nav-expand" class="btn-label">
        <span class="top"></span><span class="middle"></span><span class="bottom"></span><span class="label">MENU</span>
      </label>

      <ul class="menu-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#!" title="descriptive title">
            Link Label
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!" title="descriptive title">
            ಠ_ಠ Link Label
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!" title="descriptive title">
            Link Label
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!" title="descriptive title">
            Link Label
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!" title="descriptive title">
            Link Label
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!" title="descriptive title">
            Link Label
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <input type="radio" id="nav-collapse" name="nav" checked="checked" class="invis" />
    <main class="main-base" role="main">

      <header class="header-base" role="banner">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>
            Display Sidebar/Settings on Click/Press of Icon
          </h1>
        </div>
      </header>

      <article>
        <div class="content">
          <p>
            Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet filet mignon prosciutto ham hock boudin pork chop swine shoulder beef. Flank andouille ground round strip steak pork bacon venison ham hock, tongue turducken. Venison jowl hamburger salami bacon capicola. Chuck ribeye sirloin spare ribs, venison beef t-bone prosciutto swine strip steak. Chuck jowl spare ribs tenderloin prosciutto. Pancetta pork chop venison bacon short ribs porchetta. Short loin short ribs kielbasa biltong t-bone tail brisket porchetta pork pork loin chicken.
          </p>
          <p>
            Pork belly meatball sirloin ribeye pork loin meatloaf. Tongue kielbasa chuck sausage, turducken jerky hamburger t-bone fatback frankfurter pork loin pig venison tail. Sirloin tri-tip kevin shankle salami doner jerky capicola leberkas tongue drumstick. Tongue turkey prosciutto salami tri-tip. Shank doner sirloin landjaeger pancetta beef ribs.
          </p>
          <p>
            Frankfurter pork loin short ribs andouille kevin. T-bone tail pig chuck prosciutto brisket. Landjaeger tail fatback beef porchetta, biltong shoulder turkey shankle kevin jowl pancetta brisket pork belly boudin. Short loin tenderloin swine, hamburger bresaola rump shank ground round ham kielbasa chicken pancetta capicola. Boudin chicken frankfurter, pig kielbasa flank ball tip. Corned beef pastrami landjaeger, meatloaf flank shankle pig meatball chuck pork loin swine.
          </p>
          <p>
            Pork belly meatball sirloin ribeye pork loin meatloaf. Tongue kielbasa chuck sausage, turducken jerky hamburger t-bone fatback frankfurter pork loin pig venison tail. Sirloin tri-tip kevin shankle salami doner jerky capicola leberkas tongue drumstick. Tongue turkey prosciutto salami tri-tip. Shank doner sirloin landjaeger pancetta beef ribs.
          </p>
          <p>
            Frankfurter pork loin short ribs andouille kevin. T-bone tail pig chuck prosciutto brisket. Landjaeger tail fatback beef porchetta, biltong shoulder turkey shankle kevin jowl pancetta brisket pork belly boudin. Short loin tenderloin swine, hamburger bresaola rump shank ground round ham kielbasa chicken pancetta capicola. Boudin chicken frankfurter, pig kielbasa flank ball tip. Corned beef pastrami landjaeger, meatloaf flank shankle pig meatball chuck pork loin swine.
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>

      <footer>
        <div class="content">
          <p>
            oh bai
          </p>
        </div>
      </footer>

      <label for="nav-collapse" class="overlay"></label>
    </main>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to fade the menu in, its original opacity would have to be 0. Unfortunately, the label you are using for your menu button is inside .side-nav, so when you make .side-nav opacity 0 it disappears.

Pull the expand button outside of .side-nav and position it where you need it. Then you can style .side-nav however you want.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. Is this what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/qambxd4k/ -- not quite there yet though.

Comment: No, what I meant was taking the label outside of nav-side. Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/5qmnobup/. I set the opacity transition to 5 seconds so you can really see it.